# Linking EE Members with a Bulk Email/SMS Application

Tags: php, export

I would like to export/link member data to an Email/SMS app. When a member registers I would like it to automatically add the new member details to the app and also be able to update details through the API from the EE site.

I have an API guide from them which has all the Restful API & XML requests but need an idea of were I should go from here: http://live.everlytic.net/api/2.0/docs/classes/Contacts.html#CreateContact

Any idea where I should start? Useful tutorials or extensions to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are existing add-ons that support what you want to accomplish. You will most likely need to create a custom extension using:

- [Member Module Registration Extension Hooks](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/member_register/#member-member-register) (for default ee
  registration)
- member_member_register (if you don't use validation)
- member_register_validate_members (if you use email validation)
- and [api library](http://www.senderguide.com/api-php-library-2012-09-19) - all what you need is in *howtouse.php*.

---

For example (*I haven't tested this code*):

```
require_once PATH_THIRD . 'you_ext/lib/subscription_api.php';

function member_member_register ($data, $member_id)
{
    $url = 'http://live.everlytic.net/api/2.0';
    $apiKey = 'zyb8IwQVRf71siy1Pv8HO5szmv0jqppW';

    $api = new MailerSubscriptionApiV1_0($url, $apiKey);

    // Contact - create
    $contact = array();
    $contact['contact_mobile'] = '333333333';
    $contact['contact_email'] = $data['email'];
    $contact['contact_name'] = $data['screen_name'];
    $contact['contact_lastname'] = '';
    $listIds = array(1, 2);
    $result = $api->createContact($contact, $listIds);
}
```